# images in divs next to each other - images not completely shown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website using html and css.

I have put 5 divs next to each other and there width and height depends on the size of the window. Then I have put images in each of those divs. the size of those pictures also depends on the size of the window.

The problem that I'm having is that only a part of my image is shown in the div.
The code:

```
<div id="cotainer">
<div id="bar1"><img src="modern_combat_1.jpg"></div>
<div id="bar2"><img src="modern_combat_2.jpg"></div>
<div id="bar3"><img src="modern_combat_3.jpg"></div>
<div id="bar4"><img src="modern_combat_4.jpg"></div>
<div id="bar5"><img src="modern_combat_5.jpg"></div></div>
```

this is the style:

```
html, body{margin:0;padding: 0;border:0;}
#bar1 {top:35%;width:20%;bottom:35%;background-color:red;position:absolute;}
#bar2 {top:35%;left:20%;right:0;bottom:35%;background-color:green;position:absolute;}
#bar3 {top:35%;left:40%;right:0;bottom:35%;background-color:yellow;position:absolute;}
#bar4 {top:35%;left:60%;right:0;bottom:35%;background-color:red;position:absolute;}
#bar5 {top:35%;left:80%;right:0;bottom:35%;background-color:green;position:absolute;}

#bar1 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#bar2 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#bar3 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#bar4 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#bar5 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Tthe result is that the 3 pictures in the middle aren't completely shown in the divs
can someone help me so that the 3 pictures in the middle are shown completely

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have giver width to `#bar1` div only.

Give width to the rest of divs also.
Write:

```
#bar1,#bar2,#bar3,#bar4,#bar5{width:20%;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnq63/)

Comment: Also, `right:0;` isn't needed for any of the bars once you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Also try using max-width:100% for images;